# Override specific routing from a core module

Tags: 8, routes

I want to stop anonymous users being able to access a specific set of routes offered by the core/forum module.

specifically:

```
forum.index:
  path: '/forum'
defaults:
  _controller: '\Drupal\forum\Controller\ForumController::forumIndex'
  _title: 'Forums'
requirements:
  _permission: 'access content'
```

and

```
forum.page:
  path: '/forum/{taxonomy_term}'
defaults:
  _controller: '\Drupal\forum\Controller\ForumController::forumPage'
  _title_callback: '\Drupal\taxonomy\Controller\TaxonomyController::termTitle'
requirements:
  _permission: 'access content'
```

I just need to add: `_user_is_logged_in: 'TRUE'` to the routes' requirements.

How does one do this without 'hacking' core?

I have alternative routes for the above in my own module - with different names and controllers and in an ideal word I would also wish to redirect both those routes through my own. However, for a start I will take being able to stop anonymous users seeing my forums.

Comment: You have to implement event subscriber and hook into \Drupal\Core\Routing\RoutingEvents::ALTER event.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can override route details in a route subscriber:

*src/Routing/RouteSubscriber.php:*

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\example\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Listens to the dynamic route events.
 */
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if ($route = $collection->get('forum.index')) {
      $route->setRequirement('_user_is_logged_in', 'TRUE');
    }
  }

}
```

*example.services.yml:*

```
services:
  example.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\example\Routing\RouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

See [Altering existing routes and adding new routes based on dynamic ones](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones)

If you want you can also replace the core classes with your own classes. You can have multiple routes for one class. Then you don't need a redirect.

Comment: I'm trying to override the route `entity.node.content_translation_add`, but the `content_translation` module is doing some kind of a hack to make sure it is always called last. Any suggestions? I'm thinking about overriding their implementation of the RouteSubscriber in my module. It smells bad, but I think that is the only way left.

Comment: Yes, this module uses a very low priortiy `$events[RoutingEvents::ALTER] = ['onAlterRoutes', -210];`, so if you want to alter the route you need to override `getSubscribedEvents()` from the base class and use something like -220.