# Unable to access page when using RouteSubscriber::alterRoutes() to override display for path

Tags: 8, routes

Because of a need to be able to combine elements from two different entities - a node and a Commerce product - in one page, I am attempting to implement my own custom controller and override the built in route for the node display. From what I've found, the correct way to do this is with a `RouteSubscriber` (see [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/241880/override-specific-routing-from-a-core-module) and [here](https://gist.github.com/mikecrittenden/4a796bddfe42afdf727094b0473449b6) for examples I'm following). Based on that, here's what I have:

`my_module.routing.yml`

```
my-module.product_group:
  path: '/products/{group_title}/{product_title}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\ProductGroupDisplay::build'
    product_title: ''
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
  options:
    parameters:
```

The idea is that whether the URL is at `products/my-node-title` or `products/my-node-title/1234`, my custom `ProductGroupDisplay` controller is used. This works great for the `products/my-node-title/1234` path, but not for the base `products/my-node-title` URL.

And here's what I have to take over that base URL to use my controller:

`my_module.services.yml`

```
  my_module.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\my_module\Routing\MyModuleRouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - {name: event_subscriber}
```

`my_module/src/Routing/MyModuleRouteSubscriber.php`

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Listens to the dynamic route events.
 */
class MyModuleRouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    // Replace "some.route.name" below with the actual route you
    // want to override.
    if ($route = $collection->get('entity.node.canonical')) {
      $route->setDefaults([
        '_controller' => '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\ProductGroupDisplay::build',
      ]);
    }
  }

}
```

Unfortunately, what happens is that when I go to `/products/my-node-title` (this is a URL alias for a `product_group` node where the alias pattern is `products/[node-title]`), I get a `You are not authorized to access this page.` error message, even when logged in as the default admin user. In addition, my `alterRoutes()` method is not accessed (i.e. it doesn't hit my debugging breakpoint in the method). If I remove the service from `my_module.services.yml`, I can access the page fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Changes in alterRoutes() take effect when you install the module. After that the method only runs when you clear the cache which includes rebuilding the router table. So a breakpoint doesn't trigger unless you start with an empty router table. I find the aliasing part of your question quite confusing, because you don't have aliases in routing, they are replaced before that.

Comment: OK, so I uninstalled and re-installed my module, and then cleared cache via `drush cr`. However, I still get the `not authorized to access this page1 error, and my `alterRoutes()` method is never accessed

Comment: alterRoutes() is accessed only during the cache clear which rebuilds the router table right after clearing it. I think that's the reason why they renamed the drush command to `drush cache:rebuild`

Comment: Right, I get that, but as I said, my `alterRoutes()` isn't even accessed when running `drush cr` or `drush_cache:rebuild.`

Comment: You will only see this by debugging during the cache clearing process,  so drush w/xdebug.